# Django - set a model CharField value to the name of a field from another model

Tags: django

I have a model when I want to `field_name` to be the name of any field from another model.

I wrote this code:

```
from providers.models import Organisation

FIELD_CHOICES = [(x.name,x.verbose_name) for x in Organisation._meta.get_fields() ]


class Score (models.Model):
    field_name = models.CharField(max_length=101, choices=FIELD_CHOICES)
```

When I run `makemigrations` I get `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.`

This is the complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/autumna-dev/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/autumna-dev/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/autumna-dev/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/autumna-dev/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/autumna-dev/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/autumna-dev/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/autumna-dev/autumna/src/scoring/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    FIELD_CHOICES = [(x.name,x.verbose_name) for x in Organisation._meta.get_fields() ]
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/autumna-dev/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 733, in get_fields
    return self._get_fields(include_parents=include_parents, include_hidden=include_hidden)
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/autumna-dev/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 793, in _get_fields
    all_fields = self._relation_tree
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/autumna-dev/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/autumna-dev/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 706, in _relation_tree
    return self._populate_directed_relation_graph()
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/autumna-dev/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 677, in _populate_directed_relation_graph
    all_models = self.apps.get_models(include_auto_created=True)
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/autumna-dev/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 175, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/home/henry/Documents/Sites/Development/autumna-dev/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: I think you will need to specify the choices in your form. Since the choices at the model level are supposed to be "static".

Comment: The problem is that Django loads models in phases, and at that time the `_meta` is not ready (yet).